# Upon Click on button i want that particular div to trigger event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have a Todo App.
**Whenever i will click on check it should only trigger handleCheck() for that particular element of Div(Array Elements)**

## It is triggering handleCheck() in all the div(Array Elements).

```
 const todoData = [
        
        {id:0,todoname:"Study",todotoday:"Completing CSS today"},
        {id:1,todoname:"Coding",todotoday:"Leetcode 2 Problems"}
    ];

    const [myArray,setmyArray] = useState(todoData);
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState();

 const handleCheck = (id) =>{
        console.log(id);
      setIsChecked(current => !current);
    }
 return (
 <div className="todomain">
    {
 myArray.map((obj)=>{
          return ( <div className="todobox" key={obj.id} style={{opacity:isChecked ? 0 : ''}}>
          <div className="checkcont">
           <img src={check} alt="Check" className='chkbtn btn' onClick={() => handleCheck(obj.id)}/>
          </div>
            <h2 className="head" >Todo: {obj.todoname}</h2>
            <h3 className="todocont">{obj.todotoday}</h3>
            <div className="todoboxbtn">
             <TodoIcon />
            </div>
            </div> )
        })
      }
</div>
   )
```

Comment: What do you mean by it is triggering in all the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there's a difference between "one thing" and "many things".

This state represents many things (an array):

```
const [myArray,setmyArray] = useState(todoData);
```

But this state represents one thing (a single value):

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState();
```

So, when `isChecked` is `true`, *which* element of `myArray` does it apply to?  Currently your options are "all of them" or "none of them".

Instead of just storing a boolean value, perhaps you meant to store the `id` value?  For example:

```
const [checkedItem, setCheckedItem] = useState();

const handleCheck = (id) =>{
  console.log(id);
  setCheckedItem(id);
}
```

Then `checkedItem` would contain the `id` of the one "item" which is currently checked.  You'd then compare that `id` in the code to conditionally style your elements:

```
<div
  className="todobox"
  key={obj.id}
  style={{ opacity: (checkedItem === obj.id) ? 0 : '' }}
>
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to track "checked items" as "many things" then that would be an array.  For example:

```
const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState([]);
```

Checking/unchecking items would be a matter of adding/removing items in that array.  For example:

```
const handleCheck = (id) =>{
  console.log(id);
  if (checkedItems.includes(id)) {
    setCheckedItems(checkedItems.filter(i => i !== id));
  } else {
    setCheckedItems([...checkedItems, id]);
  }
}
```

And the condition in the JSX markup would be checking if that array *contains* the `obj.id` value (rather than *is* the `obj.id` value).  For example:

```
<div
  className="todobox"
  key={obj.id}
  style={{ opacity: checkedItems.includes(obj.id) ? 0 : '' }}
>
```

Comment: The Second method worked well, thanks for the answer mate!!!

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this code work properly you should add `isChecked` property to your data and modify the way you update your state.

You final code will look like this:

```js
  const todoData = [
    {
      id: 0,
      todoname: 'Study',
      todotoday: 'Completing CSS today',
      isChecked: false, // new boolean property
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      todoname: 'Coding',
      todotoday: 'Leetcode 2 Problems',
      isChecked: false, // new boolean property
    },
  ]

  const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState(todoData)

  /**
   * Given obj id, map all items inside MyArray. If obj.id was found, update it's
   * isChecked property. Finally use setMyArray to update the state and re-render UI
   * @param {Number} id the id of a certain obj in MyArray
   */
  const toggleTodoCheck = (id) => {
    const updatedMyArray = myArray.map((obj) => {
      if (obj.id === id) return { ...obj, isChecked: !obj.isChecked }
      return obj
    })
    setMyArray(updatedMyArray)
  }
  return (
    <div className="todomain">
      {myArray.map((obj) => {
        return (
          <div
            className="todobox"
            key={obj.id}
            style={{ opacity: obj.isChecked ? 0 : '' }}
          >
            <div className="checkcont">
              <img
                src={check}
                alt="Check"
                className="chkbtn btn"
                onClick={() => toggleTodoCheck(obj.id)}
              />
            </div>
            <h2 className="head">Todo: {obj.todoname}</h2>
            <h3 className="todocont">{obj.todotoday}</h3>
            <div className="todoboxbtn">
              <TodoIcon />
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
```